# Cannot change font color to black in Foxit Reader (Ubuntu)

Tags: foxit-reader

I installed Foxit Reader on Ubuntu 22.

I want to add text with a black font colour.

I can't do this because I'm limited to 10 predefined colours:

[image]

How can I choose other colours?